# jsf: how to uniquely populate selectOneMenu based on other selectOneMenu in each row in datatable

Tags: jsf, richfaces, selectonemenu

i am using datatable with multiple columns. first column has select combo for categories. on selection of category list of items should be populated in next combo in next column.
this is fine but changing category in one row also changes the items combo in all rows.
as rows are dynamically created how can i do this uniquely for each row??

Answer (score 0):

Bind the list of select items to the row object instead of the backing bean.